# Why Windows takes longer time to report a wrong password entry?

Tags: windows, passwords

Suppose your windows machine is locked. When you try to login to your Windows machine, if you enter wrong password, it takes more time to report that it is wrong. Whereas, if you enter correct password, it immediately enters. Why?

Comment: This is by design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a deliberate design choice: It enforces a delay between two password inputs, in the process making a brute force attack on the password harder.